# How to build project in multiple configurations to automate the build process?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution, which contains a native project. For the main project to properly work, the following steps should be taken:

1. The native project has to be built in Release/x86 configuration
2. The native project has to be built in Release/x64 configuration
3. All .NET projects have to be built
4. Both binaries from steps 1 and 2 have to be placed in the main project's output folder.

Is there a way to configure project, so that all of those steps happen upon simply choosing "Build | Rebuild all"? I know of the batch build option, but I'd still have to execute step 4 manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to [use msbuild script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2019#multi-processor-build-benefits) to build your project rather than VS IDE. Scripts are more flexible and can realize your requirements.

**1)** create a new file called `build.proj` and then add these on that file:

```
<Project>

 <ItemGroup>
    <!--include all c# csproj files to build these projects all at once-->
    <NetProjectFile Include="**\*.csproj" /> 
    <!--include the c++ proj files-->
    <NativeProjectFile Include="**\*.vcxproj" />
 </ItemGroup>
<Target Name="Build">
  <MSBuild Projects="@(NetProjectFile)" Targets="Restore;Build" Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=AnyCPU"/>
  
  <!--OutDir is the path of the execute file ,pdb.... if you also want the intermediate files to be in the same folder, you should also use IntDir -->
  <MSBuild Projects="@(NativeProjectFile)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;OutDir=xxx\xxx\"/>
 
  <MSBuild Projects="@(NativeProjectFile)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=x64;OutDir=xxx\xxx\"/>

</Target>

</Project>
```

**3)** Just run `msbuild build.proj -t:Build` to get what you want.